# Xcode debugger sometimes won't step into a method

Tags: xcode, debugging

Sometimes when I press the "step into" button in the Xcode debugger, it instead steps over the method call.

This happens even though the method is a method I wrote, and the source code is in the same project.

Can anyone explain how to prevent this?

Answer (score 8):

This may also happen when the method is being called on a nil object.

From [Apple's developer docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html):

> A nil value is the safest way to initialize an object pointer if you don’t have another value to use, because it’s perfectly acceptable in Objective-C to send a message to nil. If you do send a message to nil, obviously nothing happens.

This is not necessarily so obvious if you've used pretty much any other language, because they largely don't include this "feature."

Answer (score 3):

I have had issues with LLDB. Switching to GDB corrected this. Product->Edit Scheme->Run->Debugger.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to **Clean** your targets in XCode.  Under the Build menu try **Cleaning All** and see if that resolves your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately it doesn't help.

Comment: Perhaps you can try posting some code to see if that will give a hint on what's going on.

Comment: The problem is that the code is very large, and it could take a lot of work to isolate the problem in a small project.